# how to download excel file from php page using phpexcel

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel

In our cakephp application there have a excel file downloading..

I just prepared a view page for that .

but i need to download that..

How can i do this?

I want to use the PHPExcel plugin for that....

This is the code I'm used for that:

```
 /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
        include '../Vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');

        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('../View/Events/settlement_report_excel.html');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save("myExcelFile.xlsx");
```

But it displayed `../View/Events/settlement_report_excel.ctp is an Invalid HTML file.`

How can i overcome this  issues...

Comment: What type of format is CTP? It isn't one of the standard file formats supported by PHPExcel

Comment: i have a view page with name `settlement_report_excel.ctp` , in that there have the html table , also it have php code,  i need to download that table as excel.....

Comment: Well there is no CTP reader in standard PHPExcel, so the line `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CTP');` should throw an exception

Comment: ok i got my mistake....

Comment: i edited my question but now i got this error as....`../View/Events/attendees-list-table.html is an Invalid HTML file.`

Comment: If you need to send the file to the users browser for download, then you save to `php://output` (as per the download examples in the `/Examples` folder; and you need to set the appropriate headers as well (and ensure that cakephp doesn't send headers of its own)

Comment: But you need to ensure that `../View/Events/attendees-list-table.html ` is a valid html file

Comment: what is the fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create desired csv, xls using **simple PHP** in CakePHP environment. On execution of following code, desired excel file will be downloaded.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=names.xls"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$schema_insert = $firstname."\t".$lastname."\t".$fullname;

echo ($schema_insert . "\r\n");
```